# trace json object if empty or null or a space

Tags: php, android, json

I am trying to toast a message whenever the login details are incorrect but can't get the right way to do it. I do not know what to measure and how to measure JSON object of JSON array in able for me to fire the toast informing the user for invalid  login details.

this is my php code

```
<?php
require 'connection.php';
header('Content-Type: application/json');
 try{
    $resultset ="";
    $username = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'name');
    $pssword =  filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'password');

    if($username == "" ){
        $results = "Invalid Entry";
        echo json_encode(array("user_data"=>$results));
    }else{
        $stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT * '
                        . 'FROM users1 '
                        . 'WHERE name = :uname AND password = :password ');
        $stmt->bindParam(':uname', $username);
        $stmt->bindParam(':password', $pssword);
        $stmt->execute();

        $results = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        if($results > 0 ){
            echo json_encode(array("user_data"=>$results) );
        } else{
            echo json_encode(array("user_data"=>$results));
    }
 }
 }catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
$stmt = NULL;
$results = NULL;
exit();
?>
```

I get the result below in case of valid login details

```
{"user_data":{"id":"1","name":"jimmyjanea","password":"23456","email":"dd@ww.com"}}
```

and below is the result in case of invalid login details

```
{"user_data":false}
```

Please see my java code "Main.java"

```
package com.example.enan.register_login;

public class Main extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
EditText name, password;
String Name, Password;
Context ctx=this;
String NAME=null, PASSWORD=null, EMAIL=null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.main_name);
    password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.main_password);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });
}

public void main_register(View v){
    startActivity(new Intent(this, Register.class));
}
public void main_login(View v){
    Name = name.getText().toString();
    Password = password.getText().toString();

    if(name.getText().length()==0){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "Please Enter your name", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        startActivity(intent);
        name.requestFocus();
    }else if(password.getText().length()==0){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "Please Enter your password", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        startActivity(intent);
        password.requestFocus();
    }else{
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        startActivity(intent);
        BackGround b = new BackGround();
        b.execute(Name, Password);
    }
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()){
        case R.id.main_login:
            break;
    }
}

class BackGround extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String name = params[0];
        String password = params[1];
        String data="";
        int tmp;

        try {
            URL url = new URL("http://10.0.2.2/BirdBreedingManagement/scripts/login.php");
            String urlParams = "name="+name+"&password="+password;

            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            OutputStream os = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
            os.write(urlParams.getBytes());
            os.flush();
            os.close();

            InputStream is = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            while((tmp=is.read())!=-1){
                data+= (char)tmp;
            }

            is.close();
            httpURLConnection.disconnect();

            return data;
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "Exception: "+e.getMessage();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "Exception: "+e.getMessage();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        String err=null;
        int istat;

        try {
            istat = 0;
            JSONObject root = new JSONObject(s);
            JSONObject user_data = root.getJSONObject("user_data");

            NAME = user_data.getString("name");
            PASSWORD = user_data.getString("password");
            EMAIL = user_data.getString("email");

            if(root.length()>=1){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "login successful", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                Intent i = new Intent(ctx, Home.class);
                i.putExtra("name", NAME);
                i.putExtra("password", PASSWORD);
                i.putExtra("email", EMAIL);
                i.putExtra("err", err);
                startActivity(i);
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Invalid Login Detais", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            err = "Exception: "+e.getMessage();
        }
    }
}
}
```

I am new in android programming and I really need help to learn this language to build this application.

Comment: :- what you actually want? is that parsing problem?

Comment: I need to:
stop the program to go to the home activity in case of wrong login details and to toast a message of course to inform the user that they have entered a wrong login details. 

I will be able to do this if I can check whether the JSON object is empty or null just like what we used to do in php.. we count the row of the result set.. if it is > 0 then we got a match to our search.. the same logic I need but I do not know ho to do it in java android programming.

Comment: :- Please look at my answer

Answer (score 0):

Put some logs in your code like `Log.d("TEST-JSON","response:"+s);`

Example in your code

```
protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        String err=null;
        int istat;

        try {
            istat = 0;
            Log.d("TEST-JSON","response:"+s);
            JSONObject root = new JSONObject(s);
            JSONObject user_data = root.getJSONObject("user_data");

            NAME = user_data.getString("name");
            PASSWORD = user_data.getString("password");
            EMAIL = user_data.getString("email");

            if(root.length()>=1){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "login successful", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                Intent i = new Intent(ctx, Home.class);
                i.putExtra("name", NAME);
                i.putExtra("password", PASSWORD);
                i.putExtra("email", EMAIL);
                i.putExtra("err", err);
                startActivity(i);
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Invalid Login Detais", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            err = "Exception: "+e.getMessage();
        }
    }
```

**EDIT**

Handle basic response:

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        String err=null;
        int istat;

        try {
            istat = 0;
            Log.d("TEST-JSON","response:"+s);
            JSONObject root = new JSONObject(s);
            boolean user_data = root.getBoolean("user_data");


            if(user_data){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "login successful", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


            }else{
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Invalid Login Detais", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            err = "Exception: "+e.getMessage();
        }
    }
```

**EDIT 2**

Use `optJSONObject()` Returns the value mapped by name if it exists and is a JSONObject, or null otherwise.

```
boolean user_data_aux;
JSONObject user_data = root.optJSONObject("user_data");
if(user_data==null){

    user_data_aux = root.getBoolean("user_data");

}
else{

    //MANAGE YOUR JSON OBJECT
    // DO NOT FORGET ASSIGN A VALUE TO user_data_aux WITH THE DATA OF YOUR JSON OBJECT

}

if(user_data_aux){
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
        "login successful", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        //MANAGE LOGIN


}else{
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
            "Invalid Login Detais", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Comment: Thanks Miguel Benitez.. Now I can see in the console the result or value of the object.. I am getting this if the login details are incorrect.
D/TEST-JSON: response:{"user_data":false}
How can I use this details to send a toast message ? thank you

Comment: First of all get the data which is a boolean: boolean user_data = root.getBoolean("user_data"); and then depend what you want to show, you could modify your if statement using user_data to show a toast if it is valid or not

Comment: Can you edit your above answer as I am really new in this language and I don't know how to replace each line.. I tried to insert "boolean user_data = root.getBoolean("user_data")" and the other codes get red.. Please help

Comment: @MiguelBenitez :- there are two response in same variable , success as a object and failure in boolean , how to check the type for same variable?

Comment: @MiguelBenitez :- Tried the code and now I was able to get toast "invalid login details" but when correct details were provided.. the toast ""login successful"" does not appear..

Answer (score 0):

use below code for toast

```
        try {
            istat = 0;
            Log.d("TEST-JSON","response:"+s);
            JSONObject root = new JSONObject(s);
try{

         JSONObject user_data_json = root.getJSONObject("user_data");
 NAME = user_data.getString("name");
            PASSWORD = user_data.getString("password");
            EMAIL = user_data.getString("email");

            if(root.length()>=1){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "login successful", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                Intent i = new Intent(ctx, Home.class);
                i.putExtra("name", NAME);
                i.putExtra("password", PASSWORD);
                i.putExtra("email", EMAIL);
                i.putExtra("err", err);
                startActivity(i);
            }
}catch(Exception e)
{

}
try{
            boolean user_data_bol = root.getBoolean("user_data");
   if(user_data){



            }else{
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Invalid Login Detais", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            err = "Exception: "+e.getMessage();
        }
}
catch(Exception e)
{

}
```

Comment: Thanks Mayank.. I tried your code.. 
Then first one "if(user_data)" gives me an error of Required boolean.. I do not know how to resolve this.. if you can hel me pls..

I also tried the second code using "equalsIgnoreCase" and I get the error "cannot resolve method equalsIgnoreCase"

How can I make make

{"user_data":false}   --> {"user_data":"false"}

Comment: @fernan :- are you making webservice? i mean to say php work is done by you?

Comment: - I am not really sure if I understand your question :) I am creating a login application in android connecting to mysql.. I guess that is a web service?  I have experienced writing php before but not an expert..

Comment: @fernan :- can you get fail response  in this type {"user_data":"false"}.. false in string not boolean.  check link http://json.parser.online.fr/  paste the response in left

Comment: this is the response I get.. "response:{"user_data":false}" and I pasted that in the link you gave me (on the left side)  I got this "String parse: 1 error"  -> response:{"user_data":false} and JS eval fails (below it) says SyntaxError: Unexpected token r... I don't know how to make that response Boolean ...

Comment: @fernan can you get this response from php side? {"user_data":{"result":"false"}} then i can tell what is the exact code

Comment: Mayank Sugandhi:- do you mean from running the link "http://localhost/BirdBreedingManagement/scripts/login.php" ? when I paste that in browser I get this "{"user_data":false}" when invalid details were feed to php script

Comment: @fernan :- i know now you can able to get invalid toast but u can not access successfull taost if you get variable only in boolean.

Comment: @fernan :- I get the result below in case of valid login details

{"user_data":{"id":"1","name":"jimmyjanea","password":"23456","email":"dd@ww.com"}}
and below is the result in case of invalid login details

{"user_data":false}

can you get invalid login detail like

{"user_data":{"result":"false"}}  instead {"user_data":false}?

Comment: @Meyank :- I tried your code but did not get the login successful. I also replace "user_data_bol" line 9 on your code with "user_data_json" from line 7.. Is that correct? same as at the bottom try make bool  -> user_data_bol.. I used this inside if(user_data)

Answer (score 0):

```
Try 
Before parse the jsonobject give the condition receive string s is null or
not


  @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        String err=null;
        int istat;
        if(s!=null && !s.equals(""))  //check condition like this
        {
        try {
            istat = 0;
            JSONObject root = new JSONObject(s);
            JSONObject user_data = root.getJSONObject("user_data");

            NAME = user_data.getString("name");
            PASSWORD = user_data.getString("password");
            EMAIL = user_data.getString("email");

            if(root.length()>=1){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "login successful", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                Intent i = new Intent(ctx, Home.class);
                i.putExtra("name", NAME);
                i.putExtra("password", PASSWORD);
                i.putExtra("email", EMAIL);
                i.putExtra("err", err);
                startActivity(i);
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Invalid Login Detais", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            err = "Exception: "+e.getMessage();
        }
     }
    }
```